# Directline and Webchat?Difference and similarities

Tags: botframework, channel, direct-line-botframework

Can anyone explain how webchat and directline different or connected?I understand both are channels.But how webchat used directline internally?

Answer (score 1):

WebChat is a channel. It can be configured within the Azure Portal, just like the Direct Line channel:

[image]

Both of these channels have different Connector Services endpoints:
https://webchat.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/
https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/

Other than the servers, paths and keys being different, the protocol for these two are the same.

What is a little confusing is the fact that the [BotFramework-WebChat control](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/search?q=directlinejs) uses the [DirectLineJS library](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS) internally.

Also interesting, is that you can use a Direct Line secret in the webchat embed url:

https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/YourBotHandle?s=[WebChatSecret||DirectLineSecret]

---

Edit:
The DirectLine does offer some [Enhanced Direct Line Authentication Features](https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/25/enhanced-direct-line-authentication-features/)

[image]

Comment: Is there any difference apart from different connector service?Still both seem almost the same.Is there any difference in features provided by both?How do i decide which to use?

Comment: Yeah, https://blog.botframework.com/2018/09/25/enhanced-direct-line-authentication-features/ (updated my answer)

Comment: We do need to update our documentation.  There's a note here: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/bot-docs/issues/824

Comment: Yup Thankyou.It will help.